# Project setup with git repository connection through ssh on RAD Studio 10.3 IDE

Tags: git, ssh, ide, rad-studio

I have problem setting up connection to my repository through SSH on RAD Studio 10.3 Rio - Release 3 Delphi.

Origin:`ssh://git@myserver/Users/git/Repo/MyRepo.git`

Commits go through to local repository however I cannot push to origin with RAD Studio IDE. 
Connection and rsa keys are set up properly and everything works in the cmd.

Whenever I try to push from RAD Studio IDE it prompts me login box with username & password like I would normally login to the server through https.
No error messages or anything is displayed in IDE except for message:

```
Pushing  from project directory C:\<Project path>\
ssh://git@myserver/Users/git/Repo/MyRepo.git
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions on where I suppose to search for the problem with my setup.